# Needs detail or clarity ([Etymologie] „Streuselschnecke“)

Tags: discussion, community-moderation

I have expanded the initial question by 1000% with detail and clarity and voted to reopen just now, which will soon expire! This is the second meta-thread about the [Streuselschnecke] ([Streusel-Schnecke oder Schneck?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69618/streusel-schnecke-oder-schneck?)) after the first one has resulted in a bunch of comments being deleted, including mine.

The essential question, as conventionally marked by a questionmark and an optionally rising pitch in your subvocalization, is trivial enough to understand and still standing. Nobody complained that it could be split in two questions about *schnacken* and *Schnecke* respectively.

Although it has been noted that the etymology of the zoonym *Schnecke* is easily looked up, thereby showing a gross misunderstanding of the subject matter. And it was noted that *Snack* had better been brought before [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com). Albeit, the secondary question about relative dating and cultural identification of broadly speaking German language material surely belongs at the German stack.

Hence I'm asking that the foreclosure be reconsidered and the reason reexamined as necessary. *That's a stooped idea* – *gibberish* or *spam* as close reason – won't quite cut it because it isn't stupid if it works, isn't it?

On the other hand, what means do you have to moderate this situation other than possibly casting your vote!?